# Promise chain - reference vs then

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Basic question, but is there a difference between these 2 snippets?

```
function test() {
    var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(1);
    });

    p2 = p2.then(function(value) {
        return new Promise(x=>{
            window.setTimeout(()=>{
                console.log("P finished");
                x();}, 100);
        });
    });
    if (condition) {
        p2 = p2.then(function(value) {
            return Promise.resolve(12);
        });
    }
    p2 = p2.then(function(value) {
        return new Promise(x=>{
            window.setTimeout(()=>{
                console.log("P3 finished");
                x();
            }, 1000);
        });
    });

    return p2;
}
```

and

```
function test() {
    var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(1);
    });

    p2.then(function(value) {
        return new Promise(x=>{
            window.setTimeout(()=>{
                console.log("P finished");
                x();}, 100);
        });
    });
    if (condition) {
        p2.then(function(value) {
            return Promise.resolve(12);
        });
    }
    p2.then(function(value) {
        return new Promise(x=>{
            window.setTimeout(()=>{
                console.log("P3 finished");
                x();
            }, 1000);
        });
    });

    return p2;
}
```

The point use case is I have some condition based on which I'm composing the whole promise chain (each promise might be rejected during the process) so I'm wondering if these 2 ways are equivalent? Personally I feel like #1 is correct, but I like #2 better for more concise syntax.

Comment: Have you actually tried it? It should be pretty obvious that #2 does not work as intended.

Comment: It's about the same difference as between `1 + 2 + 3;` and `1 + 2; 1 + 3;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fundamental difference because in the **second case** the final promise `p2` you return will always simply return the value `2`, without chaining with the rest of your code which will also run but will not in any way affect the value resolved by the returned `p2`.

A simplified example is this:

```
var p = new Promise(res => res(1));
p = p.then(() => new Promise(res => res(2)));
p = p.then(() => new Promise(res => res(3)));

p.then(v => console.log(v));
```

versus

```
var p2 = new Promise(res => res(1));
p2.then(() => new Promise(res => res(2)));
p2.then(() => new Promise(res => res(3)));

p2.then(v => console.log(v));
```

In the first case, `3` is printed but in the second case `1` is printed.

So the correct version is the **first** one.

A pattern you could use to make it more readable and avoid mutation of `p` is using an array of promises with filter and reduce:

```
var promises = [
     new Promise(res => res(1)),
     new Promise(res => res(2)),
     condition ? new Promise(res => res(3)) : null];

return promises
    .filter(p => !!p) // discards nulls from promises not passing condition
    .reduce((finalP, p) => finalP.then(p), Promise.resolve()); // effectively chains all promises
```

This separates the chaining and conditions from the actual defintion of the promises.

Comment: Thanks, I (absolutely stupidly) didn't check for final return value, I was just checking execution order and that all promises were resolved... Thanks again